# Why is AutoFac redundantly decorating my service

Tags: decorator, autofac

According to [the documentation](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/adapters-decorators.html#decorators) I have a concrete service registered as the interface it follows.

[image]

Then I have used the `RegisterDecorator<TDecorator, TService>()` method to register the decorator.

[image]

The ctor of the decorator is similar to this:

```
public LogLevelFilteringLoggingProvider(ILoggingProvider inner, IOtherService other){...}
```

What I get at runtime when the container resolves `ILoggingProvider` is a `LevelFilteringLoggingProvider` having an inner of type `LevelFilteringLoggingProvider` having an inner of type `LoggingProvider` (ie Decorator >> Decorator >> Component)

[image]

Is this a bug or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: What version of Autofac are you seeing this with?

Comment: @AlistairEvans 5.1.4

Comment: Thanks; is the decorator registration in a nested scope, or just registered at the top-level container?

Comment: @AlistairEvans Thanks for your reply. Can you help me understand how to know that?

Comment: When you're calling RegisterDecorator, are you just doing that in your application startup code, or are you doing it some time later, typically in a call to BeginLifetimeScope?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's just the one scope. We use a lot of modules and a fair amount of "delayed" registration/resolution with the factory function syntax. We "capture" the component context in one such delegate using `.Resolve<IComponentContext>()`.

Comment: Try 5.2.0, the last of the Autofac 5.x releases, to be sure it wasn't fixed.

Comment: Probably also need a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - can't troubleshoot from screen shots or without all the code.